# Showing state communication with arrows as concisely as possible

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I am attempting to show communication between states in a Markov process,  basically something like this, although the arrow angles aren't of any importance, simply having that relation between the nodes : 
[image]

I have looked into TikZ (*which I've never used*) and have tried finding some info on the simplest way to create nodes like this, but most sources I've found seem overcomplicated for how simple a task I'm trying to accomplish. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need to do more complex stuff, you can use `tikz-cd`.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  &   &   & 4 \arrow[dr, rightarrow] & \\
3 \arrow[r, leftrightarrow] & 1 \arrow[r, leftrightarrow] & 0 \arrow[r, rightarrow] \arrow[ur, rightarrow] & 8 \arrow[r, leftarrow] \arrow[u, leftrightarrow] & 5
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks.

Comment: @HavelTheGreat You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A wide range of examples for drawing graphs with `tikz` can be found [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/). Also the [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) has examples and much more information. For adjusting the images style please refer to this resources.

Here a simple matrix-based solution for your problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, %
            column sep=1cm, %
            row sep=1cm] (m) {
        & & & 4 & \\
        3 & 1 & 0 & 8 & 5 \\
    };
    \draw [<->] (m-2-1) -- (m-2-2);
    \draw [<->] (m-2-2) -- (m-2-3);
    \draw [->] (m-2-3) -- (m-1-4);
    \draw [->] (m-2-3) -- (m-2-4);
    \draw [<->] (m-1-4) -- (m-2-4);
    \draw [->] (m-1-4) -- (m-2-5);
    \draw [<-] (m-2-4) -- (m-2-5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: renderer image]

Comment: I really appreciate the resources, I'll definitely be saving those.